# How to extract a JavaScript fetched information with Requests module?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests

I need two informations to generate the url to send the POST request to the server: api_token and cid, as you can see in the JS code bellow:

```
// Run query
fetch(`/ajax/gw-light.php?api_version=1.0&api_token=${encodeURIComponent(config.get('checkForm'))}&input=3&cid=${cid || id}`
```

I can get the token by parsing the HTML, but the 'cid' is fetched by functions in JavaScript. Is there any way to get this only by Requests?

I know about Selenium, but its very very slow. Requests goes directly to the point.

Comment: Beautiful Soup - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @omri_saadon, as I said, the 'cid' is generated by JS, not HTML. I only can get the token with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with Python Requests, you will need to look to use a headless browser as Python Requests does not execute JavaScript.  You may be able to see where this code is being executed, for example... if there is an api call being made to get this token, than you could replicate it with Python Requests.

The bottom line is Python Requests and BeautifulSoup do not execute JavaScript it's simply HTTP and not a browser JS engine.

Comment: By "api call" you mean the 'Initiator' in Network tab (Chrome DevTools)? In the post request there is an initiator calling a js code named "api.js" in line 244. You mean I could "translate" that part of the code in python language to get the same value I am looking for? Sorry, I'm still noob.

Comment: Yes you can duplicate any of those http calls using Python Requests it's just painful figuring out what headers need to be sent, cookies and form data etc...